# Получить случайное значение из массива объектов VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть массив объектов:

```js
var movies = [{
    name: "movie1",
    year : 2011
}, 
{
    name: "movie2",
    year: 2012
},
{     
    name: "movie3",
    year: 2013
}];
```

При клике на кнопку, надо получить случайное значение из этого массива. То есть, случайный объект, который будет при клике передавать значение в alert

Возможно такое реализовать? 
С простыми числами / элементами массива реализовать это понимаю как, а с объектами вообще нет. 
Как ГРАМОТНО прописать такую функцию?

Comment: Обратите внимание на знак "галочка" слева от ответов на Ваши вопросы. Он сделан для Вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var movies = [{
    name: "movie1",
    year : 2011
}, 
{
    name: "movie2",
    year: 2012
},
{     
    name: "movie3",
    year: 2013
}];

function randomItem(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

//alert(randomItem(movies).name);
console.log(randomItem(movies));
```